# How to Extend Algolia_AutoSearch extension in my own custom extension. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, search, algolia, algolia-search

I want to create a **custom Module** in which I want to use `Algolia_AutoSearch` extension Like my extension is about Search like Algolia extension do but my search will be about the **orders** i.e. customer want to search order when the add his number like *123* then all the orders will be shown which id starts from the *123*. So how can I set this type of search using algolia?